# Selecting a radio button in Codeception

Tags: codeception

Any suggestions on how I would select one of these?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get it via the XPath, just use
$I->click('//*[@class="checkout-shipping-method-item"]/input[1]');

Comment: Sadly, radio buttons are not clickable in Codeception. Only links and buttons are.